# where to get settings in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am new in docker for windows and I am reading what is inside in docker-compose.yml. I am confuse where I can get those settings and other settings that I will need in my webapp.

example like this the mysql setting where this setting comming from ?

```
 mysql:
build: ./bin/mysql
container_name: 'my-mysql'
command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
restart: 'always'
ports:
  - "3306:3306"
volumes:
  - ${MYSQL_DATA_DIR-./data/mysql}:/var/lib/mysql
  - ${MYSQL_LOG_DIR-./logs/mysql}:/var/log/mysql
environment:
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: tiger
networks:
  - web-db-net
```

what if I need Nginx ? what is my settings where I can get the reference setting for this ?

Comment: It is basically the same information (although in another format) that you would also specify directly in the `docker run` command when you bring up the container.

Comment: @Henry, thank you for the reply what about I need nginx how to write that service ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please refine the question, what "settings" exactly do you mean?

All-in-all usually each service in docker-compose should come with its own definitions: ports, volumes, etc. You, as a maintainer of the service should know how to run it and specify all the relevant parameters. Even without docker-compose, if you're running a plain docker, all these parameters are relevant, remember, docker-compose is just a wrapper from this standpoint.

In case you're asking about what's written in "volumes" section, its just env. variables substitution feature that docker-compose supports:

Basically you can define environment variable in a session where you run the docker-compose commands and it will substitte MYSQL_DATA_DIR with the actual value of environment variable. Another option is running the docker compose command with `-e` flag

You can find more comprehensive explanation [in the docker-compose official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/)

Comment: what about if I want Nginx how can I write the service ?

Comment: Basically it can vary depending on how do you want to configure nginx: security related parameters, connection timeouts, etc. Here is an example of one possible configuration: https://www.linode.com/docs/applications/containers/how-to-use-docker-compose/#add-an-nginx-service

Comment: Ahh ok , thank you so it depends on me how will I write the configuration of nginx and other services.